# How to store, read and delete cookies and sessions in Nest.js

Tags: javascript, cookies, nestjs, js-cookie

How to store, read and delete cookies and sessions in `Nest.js`?

Should I use this:

```
@nestjs/common > session
```

Or should I use js-cookie?

Answer (score 11):

> Create Cookie

```
async myMethod(@Req() req, @Res() res) {
  res.cookie('session', myCookieData, myOptionalCookieOptions);
  ....
```

> Read Cookie

```
async myMethod(@Req() req, @Res() res) {
  req.cookies['session']; // If unsigned cookie;
  req.signedCookies['session']; // If signed cookie;
```

> Store Cookie

You can store the cookie wherever you like. However, if you are using it for auth then check out @nestjs/passport [link](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/authentication)

> Delete Cookie

```
async myMethod(@Req() req, @Res() res) {
  res.clearCookie('session', mySameOptionsFromCreationOfCookieMustMatch);
```

**Note:** "Web browsers and other compliant clients will only clear the cookie if the given options is identical to those given to res.cookie(), excluding expires and maxAge." [link](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.clearCookie)

Comment: It depends on if you are trying to read or create the cookie. Reading it would be in the response (res), creating it means sending it back to the client in the request (req).

Comment: Yes, clearCookie() should have been res.clearCookie(). I have made the change, thanks.